# how many meditations have the word 'sati' in there? what are all the practices that are "great fruit, great benefit"?

Tags: meditation

The motivation behind these two questions, is I suspect the Buddha emphasized some meditation practices above others for some reason or other. Obviously everything the Buddha taught would have useful applications at some stage, for some reason. But some practices have been touted as being especially useful for a particular purpose, such as metta to counter ill will. Anapana breath meditation, was the practice the Buddha engaged in on his personal retreats, he seemed to favor that above all else.

The 7sb awakening factors, are the samadhi engine that takes in any Dharma (meditation practice) that sati-sambojjhanga (awakening factor) 'remembers' and feeds into the 7sb samadhi engine.

The 4sp satipatthana are defined as 'samadhi nimittas', equivalent to the Dharma that sati remembers and feeds into 7sb, and as such, would cover every meditation subject.

So what we're looking for, in these two questions, is whether the Buddha used certain key terms to designate a small number of meditation subjects as being exceptional, among so many meditation topics taught.

Two questions:

1. how many meditations have the word 'sati' in there?
   I'm aware of 3:

   - Ānā-pāna-s-sati 16APS️: in-breath (&) out-breath remembering,
   - maraṇa-s-sati : death remembering
   - kāya-gatā-sati ‍: body-immersed-remembering

They all have 'sati' in there name.
I'm not including anu-s-sati practices (such as Buddha anu sati, Dhamma... Sangha....).
And not including sati-(u)patthana.

Am I missing any? I think those are the only 3.

2. what are all the practices that are touted to be of "great fruit, great benefit" (maha-p-phalā, mahā-nisaṃsā)?
   The 3 sati practices above are.
   the 4ip iddhi pada are.
   What else? I believe there are more.

Comment: How do you read emojis? For example how how could I find for myself what "️" means without asking?

Comment: for emojis in general, emojipedia.org is a good source. If you're asking what buddhist meaning I assign to them, lucid24.org/sted

Answer (score 2):

Since the first question was answered superbly by DD, I'll try to answer the second one:

In essence, everything the Buddha taught is to be done again & again, *ad nauseam*, so that it's "of great fruit, of great benefit", otherwise he'd not have taught it. The Noble Eightfold Path is often also called The Threefold **Training**.

AN 7.46 is basically the short answer to your question

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an07/an07.046.than.html

Comment: No, it's not. I'm not asking about which meditation objects are called perceptions/sañña. I'm asking which practices explicitly use the phrase "maha phala & maha nisamsa".

Comment: looking at AN 7.46 again, it does explicitly say those 7 perceptions are of "great fruit great benefit."

Answer (score 0):

'Sati' means to remember the teachings (SN 46.3) and keep Right View in mind (MN 1117).

'Sati' does not mean to 'observe' or 'watch' ('anupassi') meditation objects.

It is consciousness that observes or watches meditation objects.

Therefore, the mind can remember death but the mind cannot remember the body or breathing.

In conclusion, to answer this question, since 'sati' itself means to remember the teachings (SN 46.3) and keep Right View in mind (MN 1117), 'sati' includes remembering all teachings & all realities when required; thus the phrase SATI-SAMPAJANNA.

Comment: If householder just would have gained a nimitta so that he could remember it and keep in mind instead of speading his "this is right, i know" bindness. So what does he remember here? An idea just arising?